# How to create round shape UIview instead of rectangle shape

Tags: iphone, uiview

Hi in my application i need a view which is of round shape instead of a rectangle shape. How to create a uiview object of round shape please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, all UIView's will always be "rectangles", meaning they will be placed on the screen using {x, y} coordinates and they will be dimensioned with a height and a width (Making them rectangles).  However, within the bounds of a UIView you can do a lot to make it appear as a circle.  Here are some methods:

1. Use `UIImageView` and set it's Image to be an image of a circle. This is easy, but not very flexible.
2. Learn Core Graphics (also known as Quartz2D) and draw a circle in the UIView's `-drawRect:` method. [Quartz 2D Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html)
3. Use a CAShapeLayer for the UIView's layers. [CAShapeLayer Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAShapeLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html)

There are certainly other methods but this should be a good start.  If you need to detect touches within the circle, you can use either option 2. or 3. and keep a reference to the CGPathRef (or UIBezierPath) and use [CGPathContainsPoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPathContainsPoint) to determine if the touch is within the bounds of the circle and act accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the cornerRadius of the layer of your view.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

yourView.layer.cornerRadius = 20;
```